# How do you create .sql.zip files from a .zip file?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin, zip

I have a folder that contains several .sql files inside of it. I'm trying to import that entire folder into a database in phpMyAdmin. I compressed the folder into a .zip file, but it seems phpMyAdmin requires .sql.zip filetype.

When I try to import the .zip file, it goes through with no errors, but there are no tables in the resulting database (0 queries executed). I have also tried just adding ".sql.zip" to the end of the file name, that of course doesn't work either. Also, I'm on Mac.

How do I turn my .zip file into a .sql.zip file?

Thank you, I'm still a database beginner.

Comment: `.sql.zip` is not a file type, it's just a naming convention. `.zip` is the file type. Are you sure that you're allowed to have multiple files in your archive? Do you have a reference ZIP that works?

Comment: No I do not but that's a great idea, I'll try getting a simple .zip file working. And yes, it's a wordpress database, so multiple files are required. Worst case I can rebuild the database from scratch but that takes a long time, so I was hoping I could just import the whole folder into phpMyAdmin.

Comment: It's more common for database dumps to be a single file containing all table schema metadata and row data. See if you can create one on your source site using phpMyAdmin because if you do it's highly probable it will work on your target side.

Comment: Alrighty, I'll check that out. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I did this and worked for me,
Create a zip folder or file out of the file you have and simple change the extension to .sql.zip and hit enter.
You are ready to go.